# How to convert mobile image into Black and white C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, jpeg

I have to convert image into black and white, which is captured by using Mobile camera.
I had read questions and answers related to converting image into black and white, but provided solution won't help me. 
Below are my image which I had captured.

[image]

So I have to save above image in my application folder by converting it into black and white as per of requirement.
I had tried below c# codes but it gives me incomplete image.

Code 1

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"c:\test.jpg");

            Bitmap bw = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
      PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

Code 2

```
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"c:\test.jpg");
int width = bmp.Width;
            int height = bmp.Height;
            int[] arr = new int[225];
            int i = 0;
            Color p;

            //Grayscale
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    p = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                    int a = p.A;
                    int r = p.R;
                    int g = p.G;
                    int b = p.B;
                    int avg = (r + g + b) / 3;
                    avg = avg < 128 ? 0 : 255;     // Converting gray pixels to either pure black or pure white
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, avg, avg, avg));
                }
            }
```

But both code are converting original image looks like below.
[image]

It's may be due to shadowing while capturing image using mobile.
Pls let me know how can I convert this image into black and white without lose of image.
Is there any library which help me anything.

Comment: Your looking for a threshold setting, really all you need to do is adjust "avg = avg < 128 ? 0 : 255;  "

Comment: Also, it surprises me that you're  having to work with the bitmap data "pixel by pixel" in *your own* source code.  (Search for *"C# image manipulation"* here at StackOverflow ...)

Comment: Interesting ...
Found [this post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/color-image-convert-into-gray-scale-image-in-asp-net/) - please have a look at No 5.).
As suggested by Trey above, you need to fiddle around with your `avg` parameter.

Comment: check this https://github.com/techmn/ImageProcessing

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the threshold to 90 here `avg = avg < 90 ? 0 : 255;`

or you can use EmguCV, it's much more faster and easier, and they both give the same result.

```
Image<Gray, byte> img = new Image<Gray, byte>("1.jpg");
img._ThresholdBinary(new Gray(90), new Gray(255));
```

[image]